# TYPO3: Issue with File upload and File reference

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have "Book" model with a "pdf" and "image" property. Both property are files that can be uploaded by the user.

I followed [Helhum's example](https://github.com/helhum/upload_example) for the image upload and it works fine. 
I tried to do the same for the "pdf" field but it doesn't work. The file is being uploaded, the file ID is also saved in the database but the file reference is missing.

Here is a dump of the "Book" object after the upload:

```
 pdf => NULL
 image => Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\FileReference
```

In the "setTypeConverterConfigurationForImageUpload" function I added this line the pdf property:

```
$newExampleConfiguration->forProperty('pdf')
            ->setTypeConverterOptions(
                'Vendor\\MyExt\\Property\\TypeConverter\\UploadedFileReferenceConverter',
                $uploadConfiguration
            );
```

I am probably missing something but I don't what.

EDIT: 
I found the issue thanks to Heinz and Ghanshyam. It was a mistake in the TCA.
Here is how my working TCA looks like:

```
 'image' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'Image',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('image', array(
                'appearance' => array(
                    'elementBrowserType' => 'file',
                    'elementBrowserAllowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
                ),
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 1,
// custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
// to use the imageoverlayPalette instead of the basicoverlayPalette
                'foreign_match_fields' => array(
                    'fieldname' => 'image',
                    'tablenames' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_book',
                    'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                ),
                'foreign_types' => array(
                    '0' => array(
                        'showitem' => '
--palette--;;imagePalette,
--palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
--palette--;;filePalette',
                    ),
                ),
            ), $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']),
        ),
```

Comment: Check out fully working example for uploading file from frondend https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/imageuploader. this might be help you!

Comment: How look your model and TCA for "pdf"?

Comment: Here is the TCA Configuration(Define foreign_types and table) for checkout file type https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/imageuploader/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tx_imageuploader_domain_model_imageupload.php#L110-L162 There is no additional configuration in the model.

Comment: It was indeed a TCA issue. Thanks!

Comment: @user6800816 Welcome! Have fun :)